# In Visual Studio 2013, I'm getting an error about missing function header when compiling

Tags: c++

I'm receiving the following error:

> error C2447: '{' : missing function header (old-style formal
>   list?)    c:\users\kiana\documents\visual studio
>   2013\projects\consoleapplication2\consoleapplication2\consoleapplication2.cpp

My code is:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
{
    cout << "Hello World ";
    cout << "This is my program<< endl;, hit enter"<< endl;
    return 0;
}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: please, rephrase your question to make it understandable.

Comment: In my program,when I begin to debug the program, an error description pops up saying "missing function header", How do I enter in a function header on Visual Studio 2013, for the line of code?

Comment: please, do not comment here, other's comments should take effect on your question.

Comment: Based on the code, the problem is exactly what the error message says: there is no function header (e.g. `int main()`).

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your code to:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    cout << "Hello World.  ";
    cout << "This is my program." << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that you just started writing code in a block at the top level of the file.  I think you meant to define a function named `main` and put the code in that function, because code like that needs to be inside a function.