# '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?) and "expected a declaration"

Tags: c++

I've been trying to develop a triggerbot for csgo.  I had a few errors, but i managed to fix them.

However, i have received the most annoying error EVER.  I'm not sure how to go about fixing this, i tried making a header and doing `#include <nameofmyfilewitherror>` and it does not work.  I wanted some help on this - I apologize for not using the code tool.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>

#define m_iTeamNum 0xF4
#define dwLocalPlayer 0xD29B0C
#define dwEntityList 0x4D3D6AC
#define m_iCrosshairId 0xB3D4

uintptr_t moduleBase;
DWORD procId;
HWND hwnd;
HANDLE hProcess;

uintptr_t GetModuleBaseAddress(const char* modName) {
    HANDLE hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE | TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32, procId);
    if (hSnap != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        MODULEENTRY32 modEntry;
        modEntry.dwSize = sizeof(modEntry);
        if (Module32First(hSnap, &modEntry)) {
            do {
                if (!strcmp(modEntry.szModule, modName)) {
                    CloseHandle(hSnap);
                    return (uintptr_t)modEntry.modBaseAddr;
                }
            } while (Module32Next(hSnap, &modEntry));
        }
    }
}

template<typename T> T RPM(SIZE_T address) {
    T buffer;
    ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, (LPCVOID)address, &buffer, sizeof(T), NULL);
    return buffer;
}

uintptr_t getLocalPlayer() { //This will get the address to localplayer. 
    return RPM< uintptr_t>(moduleBase + dwLocalPlayer);
}

uintptr_t getPlayer(int index) {  //Each player in the game has an index.
    return RPM< uintptr_t>(moduleBase + dwEntityList + index * 0x10); //We use index times 0x10 because the distance between each player 0x10.
}

int getTeam(uintptr_t player) {
    return RPM<int>(player + m_iTeamNum);
}

int getCrosshairID(uintptr_t player) {
    return RPM<int>(player + m_iCrosshairId);
}
// errors "expected a declaration" and
//      "'{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)" here
{
    hwnd = FindWindowA(NULL, "Counter-Strike: Global Offensive");
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &procId);
    moduleBase = GetModuleBaseAddress("client_panorama.dll");
    hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, procId);

    while (!GetAsyncKeyState(VK_END)) {
        int CrosshairID = getCrosshairID(getLocalPlayer());
        int CrosshairTeam = getTeam(getPlayer(CrosshairID - 1));
        int LocalTeam = getTeam(getLocalPlayer());
        if (CrosshairID > 0 && CrosshairID < 32 && LocalTeam != CrosshairTeam)
        {
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_MENU /*alt key*/))
            {
                mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, NULL, NULL, 0, 0);
                mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, NULL, NULL, 0, 0);
                Sleep(100); //Optional
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Nothing I do seems to fix these 2 errors.  I get

> expected a declaration

and

> '{': missing function header (old-style formal list?)

Comment: What lines are the errors on? The error message will tell you.

Comment: Take a look after the `getCrosshairID` function. Notice anything missing before the brace? Perhaps `int main()`?

Comment: Alright.  I'll try, the errors are both on line 53 column 1

Comment: @Mustafa "*the errors are both on line 53 column 1*" - that would be the `{` before the call to `hwnd = FindWindowA(NULL, "Counter-Strike: Global Offensive");` which would align with what RetiredNinja said. That last segment of code following `getCrosshairID()` is outside of any function definition (ie, is not in a `main()` function).

Comment: @Mustafa On a side note, if `GetModuleBaseAddress()` does not find a matching process, `hSnap` is leaked and the return value is *indeterminate*.

Comment: Nothing changes when putting `int main()(getLocalPlayer());` vs `(getLocalPlayer());`

Also quick edit, im not a very experienced coder. I've been doing this for about a week x)

Comment: @Mustafa that is not where `main()` is missing from (plus, that is not even the correct way to write a `main()` function).

Comment: @RemyLebeau where is it missing?

Comment: `{ hwnd = FindWindowA(NULL, "Counter-Strike: Global Offensive"); ..` is a `{` just hanging out in the middle of nowhere. Did you mean to put that code inside a function?

Comment: @Mustafa see the answer I just posted

Comment: @RaymondChen Oh.  You're right, I never really noticed that.  I'll try putting it in a function right now. 
Edit: Wrapping that process with the {} just showed even more errors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Visual Studio 2013, I'm getting an error about missing function header when compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33004418/in-visual-studio-2013-im-getting-an-error-about-missing-function-header-when-c)

Comment: This seems like a good candidate for creating a [mre] as a learning exercise. Make a copy of your file, then start removing stuff until you have the bare minimum for reproducing the error. That should make it easier to spot what the error is.

Answer (score 1):

You said the errors are on line 53, which is the `{` before the call to `hwnd = FindWindowA(NULL, "Counter-Strike: Global Offensive");`  That code block, following the definition of the `getCrosshairID()` function, is not inside any function, such as `main()`.  You can't execute that code in global scope.

Also, on a side note, if `GetModuleBaseAddress()` does not find a matching process, `hSnap` is leaked and the return value is *indeterminate*.

Also, `mouse_event()` is deprecated, use [`SendInput()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) instead.

Try this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <TlHelp32.h>

#define m_iTeamNum 0xF4
#define dwLocalPlayer 0xD29B0C
#define dwEntityList 0x4D3D6AC
#define m_iCrosshairId 0xB3D4

uintptr_t moduleBase;
DWORD procId;
HWND hwnd;
HANDLE hProcess;

uintptr_t GetModuleBaseAddress(const char* modName) {
    HANDLE hSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE | TH32CS_SNAPMODULE32, procId);
    if (hSnap != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
        MODULEENTRY32 modEntry;
        modEntry.dwSize = sizeof(modEntry);
        if (Module32First(hSnap, &modEntry)) {
            do {
                if (strcmp(modEntry.szModule, modName) == 0) {
                    CloseHandle(hSnap);
                    return (uintptr_t)modEntry.modBaseAddr;
                }
            } while (Module32Next(hSnap, &modEntry));
        }
        CloseHandle(hSnap); // <-- ADD THIS!!!
    }
    return 0; // <-- ADD THIS!!!
}

template<typename T> T RPM(SIZE_T address) {
    T buffer;
    ReadProcessMemory(hProcess, (LPCVOID)address, &buffer, sizeof(T), NULL);
    return buffer;
}

uintptr_t getLocalPlayer() { //This will get the address to localplayer. 
    return RPM< uintptr_t>(moduleBase + dwLocalPlayer);
}

uintptr_t getPlayer(int index) {  //Each player in the game has an index.
    return RPM< uintptr_t>(moduleBase + dwEntityList + index * 0x10); //We use index times 0x10 because the distance between each player 0x10.
}

int getTeam(uintptr_t player) {
    return RPM<int>(player + m_iTeamNum);
}

int getCrosshairID(uintptr_t player) {
    return RPM<int>(player + m_iCrosshairId);
}

int main() // <-- ADD THIS!!!
{
    hwnd = FindWindowA(NULL, "Counter-Strike: Global Offensive");
    if (!hwnd)
        return 0;

    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &procId);

    moduleBase = GetModuleBaseAddress("client_panorama.dll");
    if (!moduleBase)
        return 0;

    hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ, NULL, procId);
    if (!hProcess)
        return 0;

    while (!GetAsyncKeyState(VK_END)) {
        int CrosshairID = getCrosshairID(getLocalPlayer());
        int CrosshairTeam = getTeam(getPlayer(CrosshairID - 1));
        int LocalTeam = getTeam(getLocalPlayer());
        if (CrosshairID > 0 && CrosshairID < 32 && LocalTeam != CrosshairTeam)
        {
            if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_MENU /*alt key*/))
            {
                /*
                mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, NULL, NULL, 0, 0);
                mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, NULL, NULL, 0, 0);
                */
                INPUT inputs[2] = {};
                inputs[0].type = INPUT_MOUSE;
                inputs[0].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN;
                inputs[1].type = INPUT_MOUSE;
                inputs[1].mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP;
                SendInput(2, inputs, sizeof(INPUT));

                Sleep(100); //Optional
            }
        }
    }

    CloseHandle(hProcess);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried to copy what you sent, but I got these errors in the code. 
`   'hProcess': identifier not found
  'moduleBase': undeclared identifier
  'moduleBase': undeclared identifier
  'procId': undeclared identifier

And a few more

Comment: I already corrected that, see my updated code. You must have copied the code when I had those variables moved locally inside of `main()`, before I saw how you were using them in the other functions and moved them back into global scope.

Comment: Ok, will do.  Thanks :)

Comment: Those errors are gone now, however I get "_ already defined in Source.obj", the underscore being a bunch of commands that would be tedious to type out.

Comment: Sorry, can't help you without seeing what they actually are. Can't you just copy/paste them?

Comment: Alright. These are the following errors:
struct HWND_* hwnd (?hwnd@@3PAUHWND_@@A) already defined in source.obj
"unsigned int moduleBase" (?moduleBase@@3IA) already defined in source.obj
"unsgined int _cdecl getLocalPlayer(void)" (?getChaLocalPlayer@@YAIXZ) already defined in source.obj
"unsigned int __cdecl GetModuleBaseAddress(char const *)" (?GetModuleBaseAddress@@YAIPBD@Z) already defined in Source.obj
"unsigned long procId" (?procId@@3KA) already defined in Source.obj
"void * hProcess" (?hProcess@@3PAXA) already defined in Source.obj
_main already defined in source.obj

Comment: @Mustafa Those errors mean you are defining the same variables in multiple translation units. Which implies that you put the variables into a shared header file.  They don't belong there. Define the variables as `extern` in that header, and then put the actual variables in one of your `.cpp` files instead. Seems you need to learn how to properly separate declarations from definitions.

Comment: I'll take your advice.  I guess im just not a very good coder. I'll try anyways, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you compile a C++ file, the compiler searches for the main() function, and sets that as a starting point for the code. Other functions in the code are called from inside of the main() function. In your post, the code after line 53 is not inside any function, so the compiler doesn't know how to compile it. 
I believe you haven't written the code yourself, and if that is the case, I recommend learning a little more of C++, and then start writing your own triggerbot.